# JavaScript Replace substring within td element

Tags: javascript

After several attempts and much searching, I have not yet found a solution for this one (though I am not very experienced in Javascript!).
I have a table (which will be dynamically built), in which I wish to replace key words with icons. These key words will only be 'Green' or 'Yellow', however the date that is also part of the string is dynamic and needs to remain (I'll sort out its formatting later).

My HTML:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>SOP ABC</th></tr>

    <tr><td>Mary Coppen</td><td>Green10/5/18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Arlana Mycroft</td><td>Green12/6/18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bob Litchfield</td><td>Yellow05/09/18</td></tr>
    </table>
```

My JavaScript:

```
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var Gimg = "<img src='/Content/StatusOK_16x.gif' />";
    var Yimg = "<img src='/Content/StatusWarning_12x_16x.gif' />";
    for (var i = 0; tds[i]; i++) {

    if (tds[i].innerHTML.includes('Green')) {
        tds[i].innerHTML.replace('Green', Gimg)
    }
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.includes('Yellow')) {
        tds[i].innerHTML.replace('Yellow', Yimg)
    }    
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpz4gaqw/)

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You didn't say what problem you're facing, but I can see a little mistake, `for (var i = 0; tds[i]; i++)` needs to be `for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)`

Comment: [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string.

Comment: `String.prototype.replace` does not change your original string. It returns a new string and you need to reassign it back to your variable like this: `tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.replace('Green', Gimg)`

Comment: @ADyson It is not an error, it works - it is just unusual usage of JS conditions. `tds[i]` will become falsy when encounters the first non-existing / null / undefined / equal to false / equal to 0 etc item.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev hadn't thought of it like that, but yes, I can see it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace` returns a string that you will need to assign to target `innerHTML`

Try this code:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var Gimg = "<img src='/Content/StatusOK_16x.gif' />";
var Yimg = "<img src='/Content/StatusWarning_12x_16x.gif' />";
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

    if (tds[i].innerHTML.includes('Green')) {
        tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.replace('Green', Gimg)
    }
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.includes('Yellow')) {
        tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.replace('Yellow', Yimg)
    }    
}
```

Edit:- i< tds[i].length-1 will exclude the last element.

Comment: you forgot to fix the for loop

Comment: @ADyson, corrected. Thanks for that catch.

Comment: Nope that's not it. Now you've one one bracket too many. See my comment on the main thread.

Comment: Actually apparently that condition in the loop is fine, seems I'm mistaken, sorry. Hadn't occurred to me it would do that. (Again see main comments)

Comment: Got it! So, it was the tds[i].innerHTML = that I was missing

Comment: @JohnV, correct.

Comment: Why i< tds[i].length-1 it will not check for the last element than ?

Answer (score 1):

[Working one](https://jsfiddle.net/VIvekJain202/1vs7m46e/14/)

```js
 var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var Gimg = "<img src='/Content/StatusOK_16x.gif' />";
    var Yimg = "<img src='/Content/StatusWarning_12x_16x.gif' />";
 for (var i = 0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    
  if (tds[i].innerHTML.includes('Green')) {
        tds[i].innerHTML =tds[i].innerHTML.replace(/Green/gi, Gimg)
       }
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.includes('Yellow')) {
            tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.replace(/Yellow/gi, Yimg)
        }    
        
    }
```

What @elegant-users has answered is right.

I just want to add some explanation to it.

Why your code was not working ?

1. you used tds[i] it should be tds[i].length cause you need a value as a limit.
2. String.prototype.replace does not change your original string. It returns a new string and you need to reassign it back to your variable like this: tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.replace('Green', Gimg) 
   (very well explained in comment by @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev ).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpz4gaqw/6/)

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var Gimg = "<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' />";
var Yimg = "<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'/>";
for(var i=0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    const name = tds[i].innerHTML;
  if (name.includes('Green')) {
    tds[i].innerHTML = Gimg;
  }
  if (name.includes('Yello')) {
    tds[i].innerHTML = Yimg;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will replace the text that comes after the `Green` or `Yellow` text.

Comment: @LloydFrancis Is the code snippet that was shared in the question is not about that ?

Comment: I mentioned that it needed to leave the date intact. This replaces everything within the td element.

Comment: @JayaKrishna it is. That's the point. In the code snippet, he is using replace, which will only remove part of the `innerHTML`. But when you assign the entire `innerHTML` property to `Gimg` or `Yimg`, you will remove the part of the HTML that comes after `Green` or `Yellow`.